# Facebook Sharing App for Desktop

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

I am creating an application in which user can upload their 360 video.
In Facebook i am unable to fine Desktop  platform. My application is desktop based so it can be accessed form the kiosk(1PC) only.
My app will ask user click on Post button. Facebook authentication will appear and it will post the video automatically.
Anyone knows how to get permissions for desktop app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements#platforms